# AngularJs 1.4.9 resource headers are not passed on POST requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to set headers with $resource. It works with GET request, but doesn't work on post request.

```
  var DiscussionsResource = $resource('https://jsbin.com/my-articles', {}, {
                post: {
                    method:  'POST',
                    params:  {'asdsa':'sss'},
                    isArray: false,
                    headers: {Authorization: "Token 5b4447996855da6de109226857ec981dfe2c50a2"},
                    transformResponse: function(defaults) {
                        defaults = angular.fromJson(defaults);
                        console.debug(' -> discussion has been created ', defaults);
                        return defaults;
                    }
                }
            });
            DiscussionsResource.save({});
```

What is wrong here? It works with $http, it works with $resource get but doesnt work on $resource post.
Here is jsbin for this:
https://jsbin.com/joziniweyi/edit?html,js,console

Same happens on angular 1.5

Comment: try call .post() instead of .save. It should call the action name. Have a read of creating a custom 'PUT' request in https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource